# cocos2dx box2d win32 to android

Tags: box2d, cocos2d

Из vs2010 приложение запускается, но при компиляции в андроид начали вылезать кучи ошибок.
Может быть из-за того что не подключена правильно box2d?
Я скопировал папку box2d в папку classes своего проекта. Этого достаточно?

Comment: world = new b2World(gravity) undefined reference - это первая из серии ошибок.

Comment: Нужно больше информации Вы в С++ коде его вставляете или в Java? NDK или SDK?

Comment: Код пишу в VS на c++, затем запускаю build_native.sh, который собирает проект под андроид, насколько я понял, при этом используется ndk, после - я открываю проект в еклипсе, строю его и запускаю на устройстве. Java не использую. Проект портировался из вин32 в андроид нормально, пока не начал использовать box2d.

Comment: Я честно говоря недавно начал изучать все это дело, это первый пробный helloworld

Comment: Последнюю ссылку тогда почитайте из того что внизу.

Comment: Я пробовал ковырять Android.mk, но как то безуспешно, сейчас посмотрю Ваши варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо кучу cpp путей.

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Box2D

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static box2d_static cocos_lua_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) $(call import-module,cocos2dx) $(call import-module,Box2D) $(call import-module,lua/proj.android/jni)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 1):

Может это из-за того, что Android NDK [не поддерживает](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=166477) STL?

- [Box2D for Android NDK](http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3355);
- [Box2D under Android NDK](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/EPLgLF1oV8s);
- [Box2D on Android NDK](http://ericstobonsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/11/box2d-on-android-ndk.html).

Comment: Спасибо, добавил кучу .cpp путей, теперь все портируется на ура.